# how to pass parameter to a powershell script when running from a shell script through cygwin?

Tags: powershell, shell, ssh, server, cygwin

i have sh script let say a.sh in which i am doing a ssh to windows server (configured with cygwin) and running a `B.ps1` script which takes the parameter defined in `a.sh`.

Content of `a.sh`:

```
var1="abc"
var2="xyz"

#sshing to windows box
/usr/bin/scp -r -q /home/$user/Jenkins/workspace/job/jobname $user2@$x:/cygdrive/C/
/usr/bin/ssh $user2@$x 'powershell C:\\B.ps1 $var1 $var2'
```

this is running the script but without any parameters, when i write host variable name in B.ps1, i get blank output, which means the var1&var2 values are not getting passed to my ps1 script.

Content of `B.ps1`:

```
$var1=$args[0]
$var2=$args[1]

Write-Host "var1 is:" $var1
Write-Host "var2 is:" $var2
```

i have tried to use double quotation in my sh script , didn't work, it seems like there must be some way i can pass parameter but may be missing out anything on syntax.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
/usr/bin/ssh $user2@$x "powershell C:/B.ps1 $var1 $var2"
```

- You need double quoting (`"..."`) rather than single quoting (`'...'`) in order for the shell-variable references `$var1` and `$var2` to be expanded.
- By using `/` as the path separator - which PowerShell accepts interchangeably with `\` - you avoid the need to escape `\` characters, which you would have had to *double* on transitioning from `'...'` to `"..."`; that is, the following would have worked too:
  `/usr/bin/ssh $user2@$x "powershell C:\\\\B.ps1 $var1 $var2"`